# Had been/have been... tenses agreement

Tags: sentence-construction, present-perfect, past-perfect, backshifting

> Just the other day, I was talking to my mom about how the people who **had been** brave enough to take part in world war 2 were people we should look up to.
>
> Just the other day, I was talking to my mom about how the people who **have been** brave enough to take part in world war 2 were people we should look up to.

Are both the above sentences grammatically correct?
What's the difference in their meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called *[backshifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_of_tenses)*. When we use [indirect speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirect_speech), we often put the contents of the speech further in the past.

Let's first take a [direct speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_speech) sentence:

> Lekon Chekon said: "People who **were** brave enough to fight in WW2 should serve as examples to us".

Now let's report what Lekon Chekon said, and *backshift* the tenses he used:

> Lekon Chekon **said** that people who **had been** brave enough to fight in WW2 should serve as examples to us.

This sentence employs *indirect speech* (no quotation marks). We backshifted **were** to **had been**.

---

Thus, your first sentence is correct. Note that even in the direct speech sentence we can use **have been** only if Lekon Chekon's words were pronounced *during* WW2:

> **In 2015**, Lekon Chekon said: "People who **have been** brave enough to fight in WW2 should serve as examples to us". (WRONG: WW2 ended a long time ago)
>
> **In 1942**, Lekon Chekon said: "People who **have been** brave enough to fight in WW2 should serve as examples to us". (RIGHT: WW2 is still going on)

Answer (score 0):

The first is the correct one.

The main difference between the two is that **have been** indicates that something happened in the past while there is something related still happening in the present. **had been** indicates that something happened in the past while another thing was happening (in the past also) and now they're all done.

I guess it is still not that clear. Lets take your sentence as an example. If WW2 was still going on, You could **have been**. But as the war had ended, you should use **had been**.