# tense agreement: "I was talking how the people who had been (have been) brave enough to take part in WW2 were (are) people we should look up to."

Tags: sentence-construction, reported-speech, tense-agreement

> Just the other day, I was talking to my mom about how the people who **had been** brave enough to take part in world war 2 **were** people we should look up to.
>
> Just the other day, I was talking to my mom about how the people who **have been** brave enough to take part in world war 2 **were** people we should look up to.
>
> Just the other day, I was talking to my mom about how the people who **had been** brave enough to take part in world war 2 **are** people we should up to.

Which one amongst the above sentences is grammatically the most accurate?
I asked this question once before, I still am kinda doubtful as to whether the first one is the best one to use.

Comment: Currently posted [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/75121/32) **and** on ELU: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/292337/24489

Comment: I see there are close votes accumulating. You've added a third sentence, with **are**, to your initial set of two sentences. Maybe if you remodel your question somehow to focus more on that **are**, it won't be closed. If you are still doubtful in the answer to your first question, you might elaborate why exactly you are doubtful.